# Having a problem in CSS header with the bg color

Tags: html, css

The below is my css:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background: #cccccc;
    
    line-height:1.6em;
}

header{
    background: #80ffaa;
    color: #ff6666;
    margin:0;
    

}


nav{
    background: #333300;
    color:#fff;
}


nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar li{
    display: inline;
}

#navbar li a{
    text-decoration: none;   
    color: tomato;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-right:15px;

}
```

The below is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Website/css/style.css">
    <title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>My Website</h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <body>
        
    <section class="showcase">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, ea.</p>
        </div>
    </section>  


    <section class="paragraphs">
        <div class="para1">
            <h3>Para 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, ipsum. Consectetur omnis voluptas fugiat culpa dicta ipsa aspernatur voluptate repudiandae, ut excepturi debitis nulla impedit inventore, harum magni asperiores distinctio.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="para2">
            <h3>Para 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur dicta, necessitatibus veritatis recusandae nemo quidem! Harum sunt quas deserunt qui atque adipisci delectus esse. Animi repellat iusto accusantium est cupiditate.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="para3">
            <h3>Para 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et accusantium veritatis obcaecati libero praesentium omnis quis at, temporibus est! Quia ipsam, ullam recusandae error temporibus dignissimos soluta architecto facilis necessitatibus.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <video height="300" width="600" controls>
        <source src="C:\Anirudh\New Video.mp4">

    </video>


    <form>
        <label for="email">Subscribe us: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="enter your email here...">
        <button type="submit">SUBSCRIBE</button>
    </form>


    <footer>
       <p> &copy; Copyrights belongs to Me since 20202020 </p>
    </footer>


    </body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The header looks pretty ugly... There is some space between the header and the to of the page which does not have the bg color.. Same is the case with nav and header... I made the margin 0.. But that did not work...

Image of the webpage:

[image]

What can be done to remove them with basic CSS and not using flex box or grid (Not yet learnt them..) or putting -ve margins as that needs a lot of trials.

Thanks.

Comment: For issues like this you can get a quite good guess about what is happening by using the inspector of your browser's development tools. That can point you to what code a part of the page belogs to, and can show the box model of the different parts. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should use a reset to get rid of that. The best option is to use a global selector just like that. I highly recommend this way.

```
 *, *::before , *::after {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }
```

in your case, you could just give the `ul` and `h1` a `margin: 0` to remove the browser default margin.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Can you give more details about :: before and ::after..... I have never seen that before....Just a beginner..

Comment: before and after are called pseudo-element you can use them to make really nice stuff. Here is a great article to read. https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/  they are kinda advanced but its good to learn about them. Also, I highly recommend visiting the MDN website and look for pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes there are quite a few of these. They are similar to `div:hover` they add extra functionality.

Comment: And one last question.... Why does
`
header{
    margin:0;
}
'

Not work?

Comment: it does actually work. If it has a margin it will be reseted. But the guilty in this situation is your `h1`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `margin` of `h1` by adding this css:

```
h1{
    margin:0;
}
```